# Console program with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am currently writing a console program using .NET Core for Windows and want to execute certain functions with parameters, for example `program.exe /a /b`. Unfortunately this does not work as I thought and therefore only the first specified parameter is executed, but not several in a row.

I have already tried the following and have tried to change it minimally several times:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please give me one or more parameters to continue.");
                return;
            }

            var command = args[0];

            switch (command)
            {
                case "/?":
                    Console.WriteLine("Some help text ..");
                    break;
                case "/a":
                    Console.WriteLine("a");
                    break;
                case "/b":
                    Console.WriteLine("b");
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Any idea(s) for me?

Comment: It seems that you need a loop. Did you have already studied what they are and how they work?

Comment: Build a `foreach (string command in args)` loop. Presently you only process the first argument.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but it may be worth looking into the [System.CommandLine](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.CommandLine/) NuGet package. It would really help you out in this case.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Wow, that was quick and easy, thank you very much. It works now.

Comment: Do you need a working project or just to train your programming skills? If second, then you can use ready for use libs like Cocona or so https://github.com/mayuki/Cocona and concentrate on the problem you are try to solve